# How to i save face data in db, luxand face recognition

Tags: java, android, sdk, face-recognition

I am using this luxand face detection library: https://www.luxand.com/facesdk/documentation/trackerfunctions.php

To save face data to my SQLite database, I did:

```
 byte[] trackerBuffer = new byte[50000];
 FSDK.SaveTrackerMemoryToBuffer(mTracker,trackerBuffer);
```

But my `trackerBuffer` is always empty; all of its values are 0. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of allocating the fixed amount of memory:

```
byte[] trackerBuffer = new byte[50000];
```

You need to do something like:

```
long[] bufferSize = new long[1];
FSDK.GetTrackerMemoryBufferSize(mTracker, bufferSize);
byte[] trackerBuffer = new byte[bufferSize[0]];
```